# NSArray Sort Function on Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array called People. People array contains the Person objects. I am trying to sort the array in ascending order based on the firstName.

```
 var people :[Person] = []

 people.sort { $0.firstName > $1.firstName }
```

I get the following error:

```
() is not convertible to [Person]
```

Comment: How is the array declared and initialized?

Comment: It is populated by a web service.

Comment: But how is it declared? Can you include the declaration in your question?

Comment: var people :[Person] = []

Comment: (Again,) a complete self-contained example demonstrating the problem would have been helpful. I can see no obvious error in the code. For future readers it would be helpful to know which part of the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to specify the type of the array more explicitly when initializing it. This code works:

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String = "FirstName"
    var lastName: String = "LastName"

    init(inputFirstName: String, inputLastName: String) {
        firstName = inputFirstName
        lastName = inputLastName
    }
}
var people: [Person] = [Person]()

people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "A", inputLastName: "B"))
people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "B", inputLastName: "C"))
people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "C", inputLastName: "D"))
people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "D", inputLastName: "E"))
people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "E", inputLastName: "F"))
people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "F", inputLastName: "G"))
people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "G", inputLastName: "H"))
people.append(Person(inputFirstName: "H", inputLastName: "I"))

people.sort { $0.firstName > $1.firstName }
```

Comment: `var people :[Person] = []` as in the question works as well. It would be interesting to know what the actual problem was.

Comment: Strange. Yeah, I couldn't imagine why the example in the question didn't work but thought maybe that was the difference based on the error message. Maybe a version difference in Xcode/Swift?

Comment: Might be another of the notorious type inference bugs.